# How to get android device screenshot programmatically?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screenshot Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android)

i want to get screenshot of android device from where application launch , please reply if you have solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You said programmatically in the title but you didn't mention it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can take screenshots of running app using code or jar libraries. But to have a system wide screenshot you need to root your phone (before Android 4.0)

[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically get a Bitmap of the entire screen by using the following commands with the top level View of your layout:

```
topLevelView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap fullScreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(topLevelView.getDrawingCache());
topLevelView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

You can then do whatever you need to with the fullScreenBitmap.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have tried this but it gives black screen or current  xml view that i have set onCreate() function ,but i want screenshot from where application launch (application menu or home screen of android device).

Answer (score 0):

See this code.It may help to you.

```
View v1 = view.getRootView();

                            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: here 'view' means your layout view.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have tried this it give black screen or corrent

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have tried this but it gives black screen or current  xml view that i have set onCreate() function ,but i want screenshot from where application launch (application menu or home screen of android device).

Comment: ok.why do you need the home screen screenshot?

Comment: Now here is requirement to implement this type of application

Comment: ok.Sorry I don't have any idea.

Answer (score -1):

Go to DDMS -> Devices -> check at the top right side there you will find camera icon,click that icon you will get your device/emulator screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for reply  but i want to implement application to capture device screenshot, that's why i want solution with code